# How do I get something from my list to display in the GUI?

Tags: python, list, user-interface, pyqt4, python-3.4

I have a list:

```
def submit(self):
    self.l = []
```

I need to have whatever is in the list display in my GUI

```
    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Math Game", None))
    self.lineEdit.setStatusTip(_translate("Form", "Enter answer here", None))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "SUBMIT", None))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Form", self.l, None))
```

I get the Error:

```
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", self.l, None))
AttributeError: 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'l'
```

I'm trying to create a kids math game (a college assignment) and whatever is in the list has to display in the GUI, what am I doing wrong? I believe it may be something to do with the brackets in `("Form, self.l, None")` but I'm not too sure.

This is the entire code:

```
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import random

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    #this is backend code
    def submit(self):
        self.l = []
        if self.lineEdit.text == self.l():
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")
        #this is GUI code
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.setEnabled(True)
        Form.resize(311, 192)
        Form.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        Form.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 191, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Calibri"))
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Calibri"))
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 140, 91, 41))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.submit)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Calibri"))
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(Form)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 291, 121))
        self.widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        p = self.widget.palette()
        p.setColor(self.widget.backgroundRole(), QtCore.Qt.white)
        self.widget.setPalette(p)
        self.widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("widget"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 341, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.widget.raise_()
        self.lineEdit.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

        #translation of names from output name to edited name
    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Math Game", None))
        self.lineEdit.setStatusTip(_translate("Form", "Enter answer here", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "SUBMIT", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", self.l, None))
```

Comment: what is `l`????

Comment: l is the list, so l = []

Comment: as they indicate in the provided answer a variable does not exist until you have created it, and in your case `self.l` is created in submit so it is obvious that it throws that error. On the other hand the `self.lineEdit.text == self.l()` does not make sense, first `self.lineEdit.text` is the name of a method, I think that you want to get the stored text and so you should use `self.lineEdit.text()`, another problem is that self.l as you indicate it is a list so it is not callable so `self.l()` is going to throw you another error.

Answer (score 1):

`self.l` is only created when `self.submit` is called (which itself is only called by the callback of your button), so if `retranslateUi` is called before `submit` is, `self.l` won't exist yet. You should include anything that is expected to exist from the creation of the object in it's `__init__` method even if the value is just a placeholder such as `[]`.

Comment: So I should be placing the 'self.l' variable in 'retranslateUi' in order to execute it prior to the 'submit' button?

Comment: @DominicEaston if you ever plan to call `retranslateUi` again while the application is running (ie the language is changed via a context menu), setting `self.l` empty again would stomp on it's previous value which may not be what the user is expecting. This might be appropriate if basically the entire application has to re-boot any time the language is changed, but otherwise it would make more sense to put it somewhere it will get called during setup such as `self.setupUi` or `self.__init__`